# Find the point at which the pdf of the chi-squared distribution attains its maximum.

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions

> Find the point at which the pdf of the chi-squared distribution attains its maximum. The number of degrees of freedom is $r \ge 2$.

My thought was to find the partial derivatives of $x$ and $r$ and set the result to $04 but I am running into trouble with the gamma function. Not really sure how to differentiate it. Perhaps I am taking the wrong path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, but the idea is to differentiate with respect to $x$ and find the critical points, treating $r$ as a fixed constant:  $$0 = \frac{\partial f_X(x)}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[\frac{2^{-r/2} x^{r/2-1} e^{-x/2}}{\Gamma(r/2)} \right].$$  You can ignore every factor that isn't a function of $x$, so the critical points must satisfy $$0 = (\tfrac{r}{2} - 1)x^{r/2-2} e^{-x/2} - \tfrac{1}{2} x^{r/2-1} e^{-x/2} = \frac{1}{2}(r-x-2) x^{r/2-2} e^{-x/2}.$$  Note that only the factor $(r-x-2)$ can ever be zero for $x > 0$, so this immediately leads us to the critical point $x = r-2$.  This suggests that the PDF attains is maximum for $x = r-2$ where $r$ is the degrees of freedom.  However, you must verify that this unique critical point is in fact a maximum.